# Referencing a timestamp to another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Without using VBA, I want to reference another workbook's column's timestamp data.

In a new workbook (Destination.xls) I am using the following formula: `='[Source.xls]Sheet1'!$G4` but the value that returns is always 1/0/1900. I've also tried using the text function.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is in the source workbook.
G4 = 3/21/2018 and the formula is =IF(F4 <>"", IF(G4 ="", NOW(), G4), "")

Comment: What value is in cell G4 of sheet1?

Comment: The value is: 3/21/2018 and the formula is =IF(F4 <>"", IF(G4 ="", NOW(), G4), "")

Comment: That's the kind of info that should be in your question. And what's in Sheet1 F3?

Comment: That formula is a circular reference i.e. refers to itself. Can you amend your question to explain whether this intentional and also what it is the formula is doing?

Comment: I think it was an option. File > Options > Formulas > Enable iterative calculation. I checked that box and it works as expected now.

Comment: I didn't see your comments until after I made that last comment. I've tried editing the question, hopefully it's a little clearer?

Comment: You still haven't explained why you want to introduce a circular reference in the first place. Circular Refs are dangerous, and you really should have a very clear reason for intentionally introducing one and no viable alternative.

Comment: @BillyMadison when you say it works as expected now, does that mean your problem is solved, or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing another workbook's timestamp data, all I had to do was `='[WorkbookName.xls]SheetName'!Cell`.

I found that going to File > Options > Formulas > Enable Iterative Calculation fixes the issue and shows the cell's timestamp.